SqlException: Invalid object name 'AbpLanguages'
When following up the tutorial (multi layer) abp  I get the error, when starting the project

SqlException: Invalid object name 'AbpLanguages'.

Even if that file exists:

Full error-message:
SqlException: Invalid object name 'AbpLanguages'.

    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__211_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)
    System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask<TAntecedentResult, TResult>.InnerInvoke()
    System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state)
    System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state)
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref Task currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<TResult>>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    Volo.Abp.LanguageManagement.EntityFrameworkCore.EfCoreLanguageRepository.GetListByIsEnabledAsync(bool isEnabled, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous<TResult>(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
    Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue<TResult>.ProceedAsync()
    Volo.Abp.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
    Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter<TInterceptor>.InterceptAsync<TResult>(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func<IInvocation, IInvocationProceedInfo, Task<TResult>> proceed)
    Volo.Abp.LanguageManagement.DatabaseLanguageProvider.VveYBh6mI()
    Volo.Abp.Caching.DistributedCache<TCacheItem, TCacheKey>.GetOrAddAsync(TCacheKey key, Func<Task<TCacheItem>> factory, Func<DistributedCacheEntryOptions> optionsFactory, Nullable<bool> hideErrors, bool considerUow, CancellationToken token)
    Volo.Abp.LanguageManagement.DatabaseLanguageProvider.GetLanguagesAsync()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.RequestLocalization.DefaultAbpRequestLocalizationOptionsProvider.GetLocalizationOptionsAsync()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.RequestLocalization.AbpRequestLocalizationMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+InterfaceMiddlewareBinder+<>c__DisplayClass2_0+<<CreateMiddleware>b__0>d.MoveNext()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)


Can you try to create a migration? How will it behave
